# Where and how to make super user that can control everything?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm making a school management system using CodeIgniter framework of PHP.
I'm stuck in a situation where I want to make super user that the Principal of school will use and manage new students and teachers and other stuff related to school. He will obviously login first and then manage other details.

i. I want to know where should I place this super user. In database or hard coded it's username and password? (I know it is not good to make a table which would have just one row)

ii. And if I should "hard code" it then where should I write it's login detail so that it's secure.

Comment: Do you have a login/authentication system set up? If so, put a role column in your users table, and permit/deny superuser actions based on this setting.

Comment: My question is: if Admin (principal)(superuser) goes to "Admin Login" page and types his username/password then my system will match this username/password with username/password that I already set for this superuser But I want to ask where should I write this "already set" username/password? in database or hard code it inside my php code?

Comment: You can create an admin account programmatically as part of your application installation process. Generally web apps will have a shell script to run to set up the database - do it there. It can generate a strong password and print it to the console, which can be sent to the principal - who should then change it.

Comment: You can hardcode the username and password. What you have to do, is , force that superuser change its password on first time login. You may release the username & password to anyone. As long as, there are only one superuser OR other superusers' passwords are set by the current(first) superuser.

Comment: your superuser should be stored in the users table just like other users,add a roles table which stores roles for different user, you should have a permission table in db which is linked to the roles table and decides what sections or actions are permissible for a user by role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep the data in database keeping relation with multiple tables which wil help you later for givings roles to the users. Such as:

```
tbl_user -> Will contain users information   
tbl_roles -> Contains the roles of the user  
tbl_user_permission -> Would contain the user given permission to certain user.
```

Hence, the super user/ admin will have all the contained permissions whereas the super admin has also the facility to gib certain permission to other users as well.

Depending upon your SMS it will contain multiple users and different levels of users, so it is probably best to entry the data into database. Dividing into multiple tables.